# Add Seekbar on canvas using Jetpack Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add a seekbar on `Canvas` where blue line is showing in the image blow. When I try to add material component on canvas it says:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

and if I do it in Composable function I do not know how can I get the coordinates of line and draw Seekbar on it.

[image]

here is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.myComposable.setContent {
        graphPoints(maxOnX = 20f, maOnY = 10, 4.0f,6.0f,0f,0f)

    }
}

@Composable
fun graphPoints(maxOnX: Float, maOnY: Int, timeStart: Float, timeEnd: Float,
                concentrationStart: Float, concentrationEnd: Float) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height

        val unitX: Float = canvasWidth / maxOnX

        val nextAfterX: Float = canvasWidth / maxOnX
        for (i in 0 until canvasWidth.toInt() step nextAfterX.toInt() * 2) {
            if (i == 0) {
                continue
            }
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = i.toFloat(), y = canvasHeight),
                end = Offset(x = i.toFloat(), y = canvasHeight - 10),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 2F
            )


        }

        val nextAfterY: Float = canvasHeight / maOnY.toFloat()
        for (i in 0 until canvasHeight.toInt() step nextAfterY.toInt()) {
            if (i == 0) {
                continue
            }
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = i.toFloat()),
                end = Offset(x = 10f, y = i.toFloat()),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 2F
            )
        }

        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
            end = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = 5F
        )


        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
            end = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = 5F
        )

        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = canvasHeight),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = 5F
        )

        if (timeStart > 0 && timeEnd > 0) {
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                radius = 10f,
                center = Offset(timeStart * unitX, canvasHeight / 2)
            )

            drawLine(
                start = Offset(timeStart * unitX, 0f),
                end = Offset(x = timeStart * unitX, y = canvasHeight),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 2F
            )

            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                radius = 10f,
                center = Offset(timeEnd * unitX, canvasHeight - (canvasHeight / 4))
            )

            drawLine(
                start = Offset(timeEnd * unitX, 0f),
                end = Offset(x = timeEnd * unitX, y = canvasHeight),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 2F
            )

            drawLine(
                start = Offset(timeStart * unitX, canvasHeight - (canvasHeight / 2)),
                end = Offset(x = timeEnd * unitX, y = canvasHeight - (canvasHeight / 4)),
                color = Color.Blue,
                strokeWidth = 2F
            )

        }

    }

}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMessageCard() {
    graphPoints(maxOnX = 20f, maOnY = 10, 4.0f,6.0f,0f,0f)
}
```

Comment: You can't put @Composable inside canvas, but you can draw anything inside your@Composable using Modifier.drawBehind(onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit))

Comment: I am creating a graph using canvas and I have two points on graph. I want to add SeekBar on these points. If I use drawBehind then how can I know those two points ?

Comment: That can be done inside BoxWithConstrains, but I would draw my own "seekbar" as a circle that can be dragged along your blue line.

Comment: Thankyou, But how can I drag a circle on line ? @bylazy